# lscpu gives no output in WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm in Ubuntu on Windows. I'm in Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. I'm confused that `lscpu` doesn't give any output.

[image]

But `man lscpu` and `lscpu -h` will give me right information.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: There's no reason to expect something that uses low-level APIs to work cleanly in WSL. File a bug report.

Comment: Vote to reopen because it's not a bug and as the accepted answer clearly shows it works as expected as of July 13th. Having the question closed could mislead others.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix On the one hand, isn't the fact that this currently works fine, at least on the latest version of Windows, more reason to think it *was* a bug? On the other hand, the answer [seems to be saying, "update Windows,"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935403/lscpu-gives-no-output-in-wsl#comment1482705_935878) and that's an action that may be taken semi-*externally* to the Ubuntu system (i.e., external to the Ubuntu files that are intended to be accessed using WSL). I've gone ahead and voted to reopen this, somewhat reluctantly, but I would not be surprised if it gets closed again.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix drop by in chat and ping me, then remove this banter...

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks for voting. For me at first blush I had the impression, looking only at the question,  that `lscpu` doesn't work. Had I not scrolled down to read the answer I would have walked away misled. Sorry for reopening old posts but I'm getting Win 10 next week and was doing some WSL research. Might have to change my name to WinEunuuchs2Unix2WSL :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not only have to be at the latest version of Windows, you also have to have the latest updates for Ubuntu in WSL.

I was on Win 10 version 1709, OS build 16299.64 with WSL reporting Ubuntu 16.04.2, when when I ran the lscpu command and it provided no output. It also gave a return code of 1.

```
[ joelk: ~ ]$ lscpu
[ joelk: ~ ]$ echo rc=$?
rc=1
[ joelk: ~ ]$ uname -rv
4.4.0-43-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014
[ joelk: ~ ]$
```

After I performed a

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

and a

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Ubuntu reported 16.04.3 and the lscpu command provided expected output.

```
[ joelk: ~ ]$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 142
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               2904.000
CPU max MHz:           2904.0000
BogoMIPS:              5808.00
Virtualization:        VT-x
Hypervisor vendor:     vertical
Virtualization type:   full
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave osxsave avx f16c rdrand
[ joelk: ~ ]$ echo $?
0
[ joelk: ~ ]$
```

Answer (score 3):

When using Windows Subsystem for Linux make sure you are on latest Windows version available.

(Win+R -> type `winver`)

I'm on version 1703 build 15063.483 (Creators Update) and lscpu works just fine.

```
onoma:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 15
Model name:            Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  E2200  @ 2.20GHz
Stepping:              13
CPU MHz:               2200.000
CPU max MHz:           2200.0000
BogoMIPS:              4400.00
Hypervisor vendor:     vertical
Virtualization type:   full
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm
```

Comment: I can get a normal result either after I upgrade Professional edition from Home edition today.And I'm in *10.0.15063* now

Comment: Can you set *default font* for your console?

Comment: About changing default font on conhost read this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/06/20/understanding-windows-console-host-settings/